# Append symbolic link to served media

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, web-server, symbolic-link

I have two folders such as

```
nonserved/
    folder1/
    folder2/
```

and a served folder via Apache

```
media/
    js/
    css/
    img/
```

In the end, I want to include/append contents of /nonserved to /media so that www.mysite.com/media will be as such:

```
/media
    /js
    /css
    /img
    /folder1
    /folder2
```

I am running Ubuntu Server, I am up for either apache config or symbolic link based answer :) Plus nonserved folder is rather dynamic thus manual symbolic linking to each folder is impossible.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, are you looking for what to server the [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) of the two folders?

Answer (score 0):

symlink

```
ln -s /full/path/to/nonserved/ /full/path/to/media/nonserved
```

That will grab anything in nonserved

or apache config

```
Alias /media/nonserved "full/path/to/nonserved/"
```

That assumes you want to serv like

/media/nonserved/folder1/file.jog

Comment: thanks but this doesnt work as it adds as /media/nonserved/folder1/file.jpg

Comment: ok I gave you the basics.. just make the changed.. but I edied it

Comment: thanks but it is not helping alot as the nonserved folder is dynamic thus manual linking is not possible.